# Ajax jQuery Autocomplete Function - Start search by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have little problems with the Ajax autocomplete function of jQuery.

You can find the search function here: 
http://s500691824.online.de/new/index.php/en/. 
There is a search form input on this site.

When you type in for example "top" you will see there are some keywords appearing in the autocomplete list.

Now you can select one of this entrys and then you have to click enter again to start the search. 
But  I need the function to start the search by clicking one of the autocomplete suggestions.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="" id="searchform">';
echo '<input id="search-searchword" class="inputbox suche-startseite" type="text"  onfocus="if (this.value==\''.$search_text.'\') this.value=\'\';" onblur="if (this.value==\'\') this.value=\''.$search_text.'\';" value="'.$search_text.'" size="20" maxlength="20" name="searchword">';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="search" name="search_send">';
echo '</form>';
```

And here the jquery:

```
jQuery('#search-searchword').autocomplete({
    lookup: keywords,
    minChars:3,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        jQuery('.autocomplete-suggestion').click(function(e) {
            jQuery('#searchform').submit();
        });
    }
});
```

Do you know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#search-searchword").autocomplete({
     source: keywords,
     minLength: 3,
     select: function(event, ui) { 
        $("#search-searchword").val(ui.item.label); //which ever u have name or label
        $("#searchform").submit(); 
     }
});
```

if you are using latest jquery, this should work

Comment: I'm sorry, but this didn't helped. 
I used the code from you and changed the one line to $("#search-searchword").val(ui.item.searchword); (I used the name of the input field). 
But nothing changed.